# Why does a second sequential for loop execute faster?

Tags: c++, performance, loops

I noticed that the second loop in this code will always execute much faster than the first. Why is that?

```
int main()
{
    float t1 = -1, t2 = -1;

    Timer timer(&t1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    timer.End();

    Timer timer2(&t2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
    timer2.End();

    std::cout << "t1 = " << t1 << "ms\n";
    std::cout << "t2 = " << t2 << "ms\n";
}
```

Output:

```
t1 = 6251.83ms
t2 = 2492.48ms
```

Comment: Try adding `std::cout <<'\n';` before the first timer starts.

Comment: Why are you timing console output?

Comment: I agree with @drescherjm that it might be some initialization of anything but I threw it into a cpp shell and don't have runtimes differing that much: http://cpp.sh/5h3u4

Comment: If it was not some initialization of the console. It could also be related to AV software. That is why I asked. An unrelated option is it could be a bug in the `Timer` class.

Comment: @rustyx I was learning <chrono> and wanted to test out how much slower std::endl was compated to '\n', but... (I later changed both to be '\n')